# Shisha Va-shishim Ushlosh Meyot (366) - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

Who knows three hundred sixty six?
ששה וששים ושלש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song "Echad - mi yodeya" implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each natural number. Accordingly, there is an ongoing series on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 366? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 366, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Please, no answers that are just lazy gematria. Especially not with this number.

Comment: @Isaac Moses Can you please place this question in its correct place in the order of the number series questions? [It should currently be just above 'Shisha Va-arba'im Ushlosh Meyot'].

Comment: If you can provide a clear definition of what “lazy gematria” means, it would help the whole series. It seems to be very subjective.

Comment: 347 was nex t .

Comment: @DoubleAA there is no  347 question. So at least the numbers which we do have should be in the right order.

Comment: You can sort questions by newest, most recent activity, votes, etc. If you ask them in the wrong order, that's how they'll show up when you sort them by age.

Answer (score 3):

אבן עזרא רות ד:יז

והנה אין **בין שנכנס לארץ עד שנולד דוד רק שס"ו שנה**

Ibn Ezra on Rus 4:17

The time elapsed **between [Am Yisrael] entering Eretz Yisrael and the birth of Dovid [Hamelech]** was only **366 years**.